# Hide a block when viewing own profile page - Show when viewing other people's profile?

Tags: 8

I have a "Feedback" form implemented on a block. This block displays only when viewing the user profile page.

To stop people rating themselves, I would like to hide this block when the logged in user is viewing their own profile page.

This block should only show when viewing other people's profile pages.

I am using Drupal 8.

How can I do this please?

Here is the code I am currently using:

The issue is a person should not see the block when viewing their own profile page. They should see the block only when viewing another person's profile.

```
/**
 * Hide feedback form to prevent self voting.
 */
 use \Drupal\block\Entity\Block; 
 use \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

function zup_hide_feedback_form_block_access($block, $account) {

    $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    $uid= $user->get('uid')->value;

    if ($operation == 'view' && $block->getPluginId() == 'block-webform-3') {
        if($account->id() != $uid){
            return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbiddenIf($block->getRegion())
            ->addCacheableDependency($block);
        }
    }
      // No opinion.
      return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hook_block_access()`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_access().
 */
 function mymodule_block_access(\Drupal\block\Entity\Block $block, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $account) {
  if($operation == 'view' && $block->getPluginId() == 'block_id') {
    $uid_from_url = Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->get('user')->id();
    if($account->id() == $uid_from_url) {
      return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::forbiddenIf($block->getRegion())
        ->addCacheableDependency($block);
    }
  }
  // No opinion.
  return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

See more document [function hook_block_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_access/8.2.x)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the above still shows the feedback block when I access my profile page. Basically the Feedback form (block) should not appear when a person is viewing their own profile BUT should appear when they are viewing other people's profile page.

Comment: you need condition `if($account->id() != $uid_from_url)`

Comment: I chnaged the code above as requested but I still see the block when I visit my profile page. Here is the code now:

Comment: @ibexy you see api get request parameter from url https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Request.php/function/Request%3A%3Aget/8.2.x

Comment: Added the code sample in the original post.

Comment: @ibexy please check my post. I edit it

Comment: i think it'll working, Its had working with me

Comment: Unfortunately I cant get it to work. I suspect I am not using the correct block ID as referenced by this portion of the code { $block->getPluginId() == 'webform_3' } . I got the block ID by checking in the browser Developer tools. Is this the correct block id?

Comment: You can dubug `var_dump($block->getPluginId())` you will receive it

Comment: I used DEVEL module to get the block [ID].  I went into "Configure Block" option and clicked Devel tab. I was using the correct ID in my code. Still not working. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @ibexy you try dump it in function `hook_block_access()`